# How can I remove any footnote or notes or end notes in my Xpathselectelement

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have an html that contains this value

```
<h3 class="sgc-5">Blah blah<sup class="fn-num"><a id="r_fn1" href="#fn1">1</a></sup></h3>
```

for me to get the value of the h3, I used the code below

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3").Value)
```

and I get the result **Blah Blah1**, but the result what I want is **Blah Blah** only I want to remove **1** in the result, I try `.Remove()` to remove the 1 in the end of Blah blah, but this is not safe, as it will remove all the end of the  h3.Value that contains 1, Can anyone show me how to not include the value `<sup class="fn-num">` in the `xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3").Value` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            String xml = "<h3>Blah blah<sup><a>1</a></sup></h3>";
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var h3 = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3");
            String tmp = h3.DescendantNodes().Where(node=>node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text).First().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(tmp);
            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Here I know it's the first node. You can loop thru children nodes and check for node type you want.

Here is a link to all node types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: this works in the console how can I apply this in my code, `.Value` is not allow after the `.First()`, while `ToString()` I already try this but i get different result.

Comment: `if (Regex.IsMatch(content, "<h1.+?>")){
     _chapterName = inputXDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h1").DescendantNodes().First();
    }`

Comment: @ErwinAlcantara `ToString()` should get you the same result. I just tried `h3.DescendantNodes().First().ToString();` and it yields `Blah blah`

Comment: can you show me sample code, The result that i get is **&lt;a id="p7" /&gt;** Here is another sample `<h1><a id="p7"/><a id="ch1" href="005_inhoud.xhtml#ch1">1. Blah Blah</a><sup class="fn-num"><a id="r_fn1" href="#fn1">1</a></sup></h1>`

Comment: That means the first node isn't the text node. You can easily iterate thru the children and fetch out the value

Comment: can you show me sample code, The result that i get is **&lt;a id="p7" /&gt;** Here is another sample `<h1><a id="p7"/><a id="ch1" href="005_inhoud.xhtml#ch1">1. Blah Blah</a><sup class="fn-num"><a id="r_fn1" href="#fn1">1</a></sup></h1>`

Answer (score 0):

The value `Blah blah` you want to get from the `h3` element is among other nodes and it is an instance of the [`XText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext(v=vs.110).aspx) type. In order to get this value, you could select the first node of the `XText` type. It contains the string you are looking for:

```
string value = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3").Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value;
```

If you want to find the first text node among all descendants of the node then the `DescendantNodes` method should be used instead of the `Nodes` method.

```
var node = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//h3").DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault();
if (node != null)
{
    string value = node.Value;
}
```

Comment: `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)`

Comment: It means that you don't have any text node among children nodes of the `h3` element. If you want to find the text node among all descendants of the element then it's better to use `DescendantNodes` instead of `Nodes`. The example I wrote before, works perfectly for the task you described.